# Oracle APEX Dynamic Action to Set Value based on many Items

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I need help with a dynamic action I have on a form page in Oracle APEX 4.2.  I have a number of items setup that when changed in the dropdowns fire the dynamic action to return either 'Complete' or 'In Porgess'.  When the page loads or when the an item is changed I keep getting null.  I checked the debug also and it has verified that I am just getting null.  Here is my PL/SQL Function body.

```
declare l_status varchar2(255);
begin
if
:p2_dbst_1_1 = 'Complete' AND 

:p2_dbst_1_2 = 'Complete' AND

:p2_dbst_1_3 = 'Complete' AND 

:p2_dbst_2_1 = 'Complete' AND

:p2_dbst_2_2 = 'Complete' AND

:p2_dbst_2_3 = 'Complete' AND

(:p2_dbst_2_3A = 'Complete' OR 
:p2_dbst_2_3A = 'NA') AND

:p2_dbst_2_4 = 'Complete' AND

:p2_dbst_3_1 = 'Complete'

THEN l_status := 'Complete';
ELSE l_status := 'In Progress';
end if;
end;
```

The only item that can be 'Complete' or 'NA' is 3A.

I do have all of these items in the Change Item separated by commas and I am returning the l_status into dbst_3_1 as a display only item.

Any ideas on why I keep getting null and not Complete or In Progress?  Also I need it to continue to run dynamically on the page over and over as the user is changing the items.  Is there where the 'Dynamic Scope' comes in?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't know, but why is this a PL/SQL dynamic action?  That will fire an AJAX round-trip to the server.  Can't this all be done on the client in Javascript?

Comment: How are your select lists defined? What does your list of values select look like? @TonyAndrews You're right, though I'd understand if javascript knowledge may be an issue for OP.

Comment: Shouldn't the block end with `return l_status;`?

Comment: Hi,Yes I do not know JS at all really, but I was missing that return ;(  Duhh..This dynamic action does not updates 'dynamically' when I change it in the items...either with the JS or PL/SQL.  Right now, now matter what it returns 'In Progress', even if all are 'Complete'.    My select lists are static dropdowns.  STATIC2:In Progress;In Progress,Complete;Complete.  Thanks for your help and advice.

Comment: One other point about my page.  I am using the jquery Accordian on this page...that would not count as a Partial Page Refresh correct?  I have three regions where these items reside and wondering if I need a jquery selector so that I use use Dynamic Scope and the dynamic action would fire on each change of the items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you dont forget to submit and return the page items. You'll find where to list them under the PL/SQL code box, named **Page items to Submit** and **Page items to Return**

You should add a line that saves l_status on dbmst_3_1. then add it to page items to return.

```
declare 

l_status varchar2(255);

begin
  if
   :P2_DBST_1_1   = 'Complete' AND 
   :P2_DBST_1_2   = 'Complete' AND    
   :P2_DBST_1_3   = 'Complete' AND     
   :P2_DBST_2_1   = 'Complete' AND    
   :P2_DBST_2_2   = 'Complete' AND    
   :P2_DBST_2_3   = 'Complete' AND    
   (:P2_DBST_2_3A = 'Complete' OR 
   :P2_DBST_2_3A  = 'NA') AND    
   :P2_DBST_2_4   = 'Complete' AND    
   :P2_DBST_3_1   = 'Complete' THEN 

     l_status := 'Complete';
   ELSE          
     l_status := 'In Progress';
  end if;

  :dbst_3_1 := l_status;
end;
```

Your **Page items to Submit** should contain these items:
  P2_DBST_1_1,P2_DBST_1_2,P2_DBST_1_3,P2_DBST_2_1,P2_DBST_2_2,P2_DBST_2_3,P2_DBST_2_3A,P2_DBST_2_3A,P2_DBST_2_4,P2_DBST_3_1

while **Page items to Return** should contain these item:

DBST_3_1

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I tried this exactly as you have and I get a token error.  I also tried putting the item to Return as P2_DBST_3_1 and removed it from the code as it should not be evaluated as part of the if statement, but instead serve as a container for the value to be returned.  If I change one of the items it works the first time but for some reason APEX does not continue to run expression after toggling the same or difference items in the submit section.  Any idea why I lose this ability.  I don't have any PPR (Partial Page Refreshes) only a Javascript Accordian. thanks

Comment: Solution =  end if;

  return l_status; instead of 

  :dbst_3_1 := l_status; with page item return p2_dbst_3_1;  Thanks everyone for their time and help :)

Answer (score 3):

Your PL/SQL is missing this just before the end:

```
return l_status;
```

However I think this Javascript expression could be used instead of the PL/SQL, which would be more efficient:

```
(
$v('P2_DBST_1_1') == 'Complete' && 
$v('P2_DBST_1_2') == 'Complete' &&
$v('P2_DBST_1_3') == 'Complete' && 
$v('P2_DBST_2_1') == 'Complete' &&
$v('P2_DBST_2_2') == 'Complete' &&
$v('P2_DBST_2_3') == 'Complete' &&
($v('P2_DBST_2_3A') == 'Complete' || 
$v('P2_DBST_2_3A') == 'NA') &&
$v('P2_DBST_2_4') == 'Complete' &&
$v('P2_DBST_3_1') == 'Complete'
)
? 'Complete'
: 'In Progress'
```